# Custom sorting, component not showing updated data react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have added `sort` in my `custom table`. Sorting is working if I see it in `console`, It shows the data is getting updated.
But my `TableBody` is not getting updated after once.

Not sure what's happening.

TableWrapper.js

```
const TableWrapper = ({...props}) => {
  const { tableData, columns } = props;
  const [ visibleData, setVisibleData ] = useState([])
  const sortColumn = (dataIndex, sortOrder) => {
    let sortedData = tableData.data.firstResponse.sort(function(a, b){
      if(a.dataIndex < b.dataIndex) return -1;  // Ascending Order
      if(a.dataIndex > b.dataIndex) return 1;   // Descending Order  
      return 0; // Default
  })
  if (sortOrder === 'desc') {
    sortedData.reverse();
  }    
      console.log(dataIndex, sortOrder)
      console.log(sortedData)
      setVisibleData(sortedData);
  }
    
  return (
    <>
    <table>
      <TableHead headers={columns} isCheckBox={true} isSelectAll={selectAll} selectAllChecked={selectAllChecked} sortColumn={sortColumn} />
      <TableBody rows={tableData} tableData={visibleData} headers={columns} isCheckBox={true} isSelectAll={selectAll} isCheckBoxChecked={selectedCheckBox} />
    </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default TableWrapper;
```

TableHead.js

```
const TableHead = ({...props}) => {
  const { headers, isCheckBox, isSelectAll, selectAllChecked, sortColumn } = props;
  const [sortorState, setSortorState] = useState("desc");

  const checkRef = useRef();

  const getSortorState = sortorState => {
    switch (sortorState) {
      case "asc":
        return "desc";
      case "desc":
        return "asc";
      default:
        return "desc";
    }
  };

  const handleSorterChange = (dataIndex, sortOrder) => {
    const updatedSortorState = getSortorState(sortOrder);
    setSortorState(updatedSortorState);
    sortColumn(dataIndex, updatedSortorState)
  };

  return (
    <thead>
        <tr>
          {
            isCheckBox && 
              <th key={`table-header-checkBox`}><input id="select-all-checkBox" type="checkbox" onClick={selectAllChecked} ref={checkRef} /></th>
          }
        {headers.map(item => {
          const { key, field, style, header, sortable} = item
          return (
            <>
            {sortable ? 
              <th
                className={"table-header" + " sortable"}
                onClick={() =>
                  handleSorterChange(field, sortorState)
                }
              >
              <span>{header}</span>
              </th>
            : 
            <th
              key={`table-header-${key}`}
              style={style}>
              {header}
            </th>
            }
            </>
          )})}
        </tr>
    </thead>
  );
};

export default TableHead;
```

I need some help on this, why It's not getting updated.

`Or is there any better way to achieve the sorting?`

In the picture, I am trying to sort the `first name`, If you see the console the data is getting sorted but after one time the `table data` is not getting updated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mutating the `props.tableData.data.firstResponse` array, first when `.sort` is called on it, and again, conditionally when it's reversed. These are both in-place algorithms, meaning they update the array they function over.

[Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array ***in place*** and returns
> the sorted array.

[Array.prototype.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

> The `reverse()` method reverses an array ***in place***. The first array
> element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the
> first.

You will want to first create a shallow copy of the `props.tableData.data.firstResponse` array to sort and conditionally reverse. It also seems that `dataIndex` is actually a field property you want to sort by, so it's likely really to be used as a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) (*there is no `dataIndex` property so you are comparing undefined values*).

```
const TableWrapper = ({ tableData, columns }) => {
  const [ visibleData, setVisibleData ] = useState([]);

  const sortColumn = (field, sortOrder) => {
    const sortedData = tableData.data.firstResponse
      .slice()                             // <-- create shallow copy of array
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a[field] < b[field]) return -1; // <-_ use computed property
        if(a[field] > b[field]) return 1;  // <-_ use computed property
        return 0;
      });

    if (sortOrder === 'desc') {
      sortedData.reverse();
    } 
    setVisibleData(sortedData);
  }
    
  return (
    <table>
      <TableHead
        headers={columns}
        isCheckBox={true}
        isSelectAll={selectAll}
        selectAllChecked={selectAllChecked}
        sortColumn={sortColumn}
      />
      <TableBody
        rows={tableData}
        tableData={visibleData}
        headers={columns}
        isCheckBox={true}
        isSelectAll={selectAll}
        isCheckBoxChecked={selectedCheckBox}
      />
    </table>
  );
};
```

A simpler sort toggle function (*it can only ever be one or the other, right?*):

```
const getSortorState = sortorState => sortorState === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
```